# Dynamically creating checkboxes from database using MVVM

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

How to create dynamic checkboxes at run time from the databases values using MVVM pattern. I have set all the table columns as get;set; properties in Model. But not getting how to create the checkboxes using MVVM and where to put what means where to put database connections and functions for that and how to bind the dynamically created checkboxes in xaml and in viewmodel?

Kindly Suggest?

Thanks

Comment: I don't exactly know what you're trying to do, but one solution might be the use of 'ItemTemplates'. You need to give some additional infos, though. What type of container do you use ? ListView ? DataGrid ? What kind of object is your data ? Raw Objects or Datarows ?

Comment: http://thejoyofcode.com/ViewModels_and_CheckListBoxes.aspx

Comment: Hi,

means I am getting a list from the database and binding it to the listbox. Now I want to add checkbox against each list item in the listbox. How to generate the checkbox at run time and place them against the list item. I want to preselect the checkbox values from the database.

Kindly suggest?

Thanks